# Pointers to Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello I’m new to c++ and I’m trying to figure out how to use pointers to change the same object.

If I have a vector of pointers for example

`std::vector<myclass*> top;`

and lets say the top[0] = NULL I want to use another pointer to change it

```
myclass* other = top[0];
other = new myclass();
```

So that when I access top[0] it will be pointed to the new object created? Sorry a little confusing but that’s the idea.

Comment: `top[0] = new myclass`?

Comment: I’m sorry I edited what I was trying to mean.

Comment: In C++ you may better use reference, not pointer in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, you had a vector of `int`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
```

and then did something like

```
int other = vec[0];
other = 5;
```

I think most people would understand that the assignment `other = 5;` would change the value of the variable `other` only, not the value of `vec[0]`.

Now lets take your code:

```
myclass* other = top[0];
other = new myclass();
```

It's exactly the same thing here: The assignment `other = new myclass();` only changes the variable `other` and where it points, it doesn't change `top[0]`.

What I *think* you want is to use `other` as a *reference* to the value in `top[0]`, which you can do by using references:

```
myclass*& other = top[0];
other = new myclass();
```

Now `other` will be a reference to the value in `top[0]`, so the assignment will change `top[0]`.

And for completeness sake, and keeping with the pointer-to-pointer thing in the title, you could of course solve it through pointers to pointers:

```
myclass** other = &top[0];
*other = new myclass();
```

With the above `other` will be a pointer to `top[0]`, and you need to use the dereference operator `*` (as in `*other`) in the assignment to change the value at `top[0]`. I really recommend the references though.

Answer (score 0):

You've got things a bit backward:

```
myclass *other = new myclass();
top[0] = other;
```

EDIT:

You need to take the address of the vector element:

```
std::vector<myclass*> top(5);
myclass *other = new myclass();
other->x = 4;
top[0] = other;
printf("top[0].x=%d\n", top[0]->x);
myclass **p = &top[0];
(*p)->x = 5;
printf("top[0].x=%d\n", top[0]->x);
```

Output:

```
top[0].x=4
top[0].x=5
```

Comment: No I’m sorry i edited up top, i need two pointers that would change value of what it’s pointing to?